# LCD weird characters

Tags: c, arm, interrupt

I have been working on a project in which I need to show numeric outputs via 2x16 LCD display. Also, I am using a timer interruption in a program. Until the addition of interruption, LCD works without flaws. After I started to use interruption for proper timing maintenance, LCD display started to show weird characters.I couldn't find the proper reasons for this problem. I am using LPC2148 ARM7TDMI-S controller. Programming is developed in keil SDE. What could be the reason for this problem? 
I have added a statement that should be executed on interruption and LCD update function here.

```
  __irq void T0ISR(void)  // interruption function
{
    long int regVal;
    regVal = T0IR; //Read current IR value


if(RUN_STATUS == 1)
{
if(Input>=90)
{
    PWMMR2 = 7500;  // T-ON=75% , Hence 75% Bright
    PWMLER = (1<<2); // Update Latch Enable bit for PWMMR2
}

else
    {
    PWMMR2 = 3200;  // T-ON=32% , Hence 32% Bright
    PWMLER = (1<<2); // Update Latch Enable bit for PWMMR2
    }

    RUN_STATUS = RUN_OFF;    // Turn off the status in order to maintain the sync b/w displaying and interrupting
}


void update_lcd()             // update the status of LED
{

    LCD_STRING("S.P:  ");  

     LCD_STRING(SP);     // prints setpoint in display


   LCD_CMD(0xC0);                

   LCD_STRING(Ip);             //prints input data in display

     //delay(10);
    LCD_CMD(0x01);

    RUN_STATUS = RUN_ON;  // Enable interruption's function after updating LCD


}
```

Comment: If your interrupt is being triggered while data is being sent to the LCD controller it could mess with the timing, which could easily cause communication to get out of sync and you end up with garbage data on the display. Try minimizing the amount of code that's run in the interrupt; maybe set a flag somewhere then do the work *after* you've finished writing to the display?

Comment: Hi nemequ, I have tried that too. Setting a flag for interruption function after LCD display function is executed in a loop. But the result is same.
In interruption, function body is,
if(flag==set)
{
if(condition)
{
Do something;
}
else
{
Do something;
}
}
This concept works fine. 
In LCD display function,
update_lcd()
{
other lcd functions;
flag=set  // for enabling interruption's function
}

Comment: I doubt you're going to have much luck getting an answer here, then. It's hard to debug an issue like this without access to the software, much less the hardware. The first thing I'd do is try to isolate exactly what triggers the problem in the software (what happens when you install an interrupt handler that does nothing), then start looking for dumb errors on the hardware side (maybe you left a pin floating or something). As a last resort, I'd grab the datasheet and a scope and work my way up from there as best I could…

Comment: Even without access to the hardware, seeing the code would be helpful. Please show it - and not in a comment. [edit] your question for additional information. The expectation for a [mcve] are relaxed here, but you should still provide one.